# PHP Spreadsheet 1 value per spreadsheet

Tags: php, spreadsheet

I've got an array of hotels below. I'm planning to export it to a spreadsheet using [Php spreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). My goal is to get 1 spreadsheet per hotel so in the array `$hotels` below, I'd expect 2 spreadsheets will be created.

This is what I wanted to render in each spreadsheet.

Spreadsheet 1:

```
   | Property  | Hotel 1 | Hotel 1
   | Room Name | Room 1  | Room 2
   ...
```

Spreadsheet 2:

```
   | Property  | Hotel 2 | Hotel 2 | Hotel 2
   | Room Name | Room 3  | Room 4  | Room 5
   ...
```

But what I've got so far is it shows all of the hotels like this

```
   | Property  | Hotel 1 | Hotel 1 | Hotel 2 | Hotel 2 | Hotel 3 
   | Room Name | Room 1  | Room 2  | Room 3  | Room 4  | Room 5
   ...
```

The hotel array.

```
$hotels = [
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'Hotel 1',
    'rooms' => [
        0 => [
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'Room1',
            'default_price' => 50,
            'options' => [
                0 => [
                    'date' => '12-04-2022',
                    'price' => 100,
                ]...
            ]
        ],
        1 => [
            'id' => 2,
            'title' => 'Room2',
            'default_price' => 120,
            'options' => [
                0 => [
                    'date' => '11-04-2022',
                    'price' => 200,
                ]...
            ]
        ],
    ],
    
    'id' => 2,
    'title' => 'Hotel 2',
    'rooms' => [
        0 => [
            'id' => 3,
            'title' => 'Room3',
            'default_price' => 50,
            'options' => [
                0 => [
                    'date' => '12-04-2022',
                    'price' => 100,
                ]...
            ]
        ],
        1 => [
            'id' => 4,
            'title' => 'Room4',
            'default_price' => 120,
            'options' => [
                0 => [
                    'date' => '11-04-2022',
                    'price' => 200,
                ]...
            ]
        ],
        1 => [
            'id' => 5,
            'title' => 'Room5',
            'default_price' => 120,
            'options' => [
                0 => [
                    'date' => '11-04-2022',
                    'price' => 200,
                ]...
            ]
        ],
    ]
];
```

This is what I've done so far:
The first one (`$sheetPrice->setCellValue($alphabets[$hotelKey+2].'2' , $hotel->title)`) is not working like what I wanted.

The second one (`$sheetPrice->setCellValue($alphabets[$key].'2' , $hotel->title)`) is showing all the hotels instead of 1 hotel rooms value per spreadsheet.

```
$sheetPrice->setCellValue('B2', 'Property');
$sheetAvailability->setCellValue('B2', 'Property');

$sheetPrice->setCellValue('B3', 'Unit Type');
$sheetAvailability->setCellValue('B3', 'Unit Type');

$sheetPrice->setCellValue('B4', 'Unit Guests');
$sheetAvailability->setCellValue('B4', 'Unit Guests');

foreach ($hotels as $hotelKey => $hotel) {

    // not working
    //$sheetPrice->setCellValue($alphabets[$hotelKey+2].'2' , $hotel->title);

    // check if it has rooms
    if (count($rooms) > 0) {
        // extract rooms
        foreach ($rooms as $key => $room) {
             $key = $key+2;
             $sheetPrice->setCellValue($alphabets[$key].'2' , $hotel->title);
             // rest of the rooms set cell value
             ...
        }

        $filename = $hotel->title . '.xlsx';
        $file = $this->basename . '/excel_export/' . $filename;
        $writer->save($file);
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure if there are any post like this or maybe I just need the right words to google the problem but if there is please link it below. Thanks!

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want a different file for each hotel ? Am I right ?

Comment: @GazmendSahiti yes. different file for each hotel. sorry, it was a bit late. out of town during weekends.

Comment: The array structure you have shown, does not make sense in combination with the code. This appears to be missing a "dimension."

Comment: And if you really want a separate Excel _file_ for each hotel (and not just one that contains a separate _sheet_ for each hotel) - then the code to create a new one would probably belong _into_ the shown loop.

Comment: I will give you my most common piece of advice: Break the Problem Down. Forget about the PHPSpreadsheet code for a while, and look carefully at the exact input you have, and how you want to split it up. Write code to output some simple text or HTML strings like "Start of 'Hotel 1'", and "Prices for 'Room 1'", and get the looping and if logic right, then add back the logic to open and save spreadsheets.

Comment: Meanwhile, the code shown is not a [mcve] - the array structure is invalid (it contains duplicate keys), and the code is incomplete (e.g. there is no definition of `$sheetPrice`). That makes it impossible for us to help you debug your code, because the code we're looking at is not the code you're debugging, and may not reproduce the problem at all. I cannot vote to close, because you have placed a bounty, so I will downvote instead.

Comment: @CBroe I will try to do what you said thanks.

Comment: @IMSoP is it because I repeated the keys from the hotel array and rooms array? Also, thanks for the advice. Will try to do that too. Appreciate it! Sorry if it's kinda minimal, feel free to close it.

Comment: @the_lorem_ipsum_guy Yes, as CBroe says your loop implies you have something like `[ ['id' => 1], ['id' => 2] ]` but the example shown has `[ 'id' => 1, 'id' => 2 ]`, which will never work. Simplifying examples is a good thing, but remember to always test the simplified version before posting, to make sure it actually works and reproduces the problem.

Comment: @IMSoP no worries thanks a lot! I just have to manually create the array which causes a problem since, in my real data, the array is quite too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing in the same sheet over and over.
You need to create a new spreadsheet, fill it with rows then save for each hotel.
Also that array structure you did provide is invalid  there can't be two indexes with the same name.

```
  foreach ($hotels as $hotel){
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        // do your things, set the header, add the rows etc
        
        $filename = $hotel->title . '.xlsx';
        $file = $this->basename . '/excel_export/' . $filename;
        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save($filename);
    }
```